# TextView не корректно отображает HTML разметку.

Tags: ios, swift

Ни как не могу понять в чем дело, на одном `ViewController` `TextView` принимает `HTML` разметку полностью (жирность и тд), на другом `ViewController2` `TextView` не делает заголовок текста жирным, что важно я юзаю один и тот же текст.

Вот сам текст:

```
<h2><strong>Условия подписки на приложение Lala:</strong></h2><br>
Подписка - это свободный и неограниченный доступ ко всем материалам приложения с устройств под управлением операционной системы iOS.<br><br>
<ul>
<li>Срок подписки соответствует выбранному периоду подписки.</li>
<li>Стоимость подписки указывается в момент подтверждения покупки. Оплата производится на счет iTunes.</li>
<li>Подписку на текущий оплаченный период отменить нельзя.</li>
<li>По правилам iTunes продление подписки осуществляется автоматически за 24 часа до окончания текущего периода подписки.</li>
<li>Автоматическое продление подписки можно отключить в настройках операционной системы вашего устройства. Обратите внимание, что это надо сделать за 24 часа до окончания текущего срока подписки. При удалении приложения автоматической отмены подписки не происходит.</li>
</ul> .
```

Вот как все выглядит на рабочем варианте:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А вот как на не совсем рабочем (так как что то работает, а что то нет):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В сториборде были настройки размера шрифта для iPad версии, после того как я их "снес", у меня все заработало.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]